# changing vocabularies to value "1" in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame. I am going the replace all values in ADR with value 1. Th

```
Index    ADR
1        Fair
2        good
3        best
4        tr
5        heavy
```

This is my code:

```
df1['ADR'] = df1.replace(r'\w+', 1, regex=True)
df1['ADR'] = df1.replace(r'\w+',r'\ 1', regex=True)
```

But both of them create the following dataset:

```
  Index    ADR
    1        1
    2        2
    3        3
    4        4
    5        5
```

I need all the values in ADR to be "1". This is the desired output.

```
  Index    ADR
    1        1
    2        1
    3        1
    4        1
    5        1
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: why not `df1['ADR'] = 1`? If that is what you want. But, I'm curious why and where you would use only 1's.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: can you show us your output when you tried `df1['ADR'] = 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need specify column for replace `ADR`:

```
df1['ADR'] = df1['ADR'].replace(r'\w+', 1, regex=True)
print (df1)
   Index  ADR
0      1    1
1      2    1
2      3    1
3      4    1
4      5    1
```

Another solution is replace with specifying column by `dict`:

```
df1 = df1.replace({'ADR':{ r'\w+': 1}}, regex=True)
print (df1)
   Index  ADR
0      1    1
1      2    1
2      3    1
3      4    1
4      5    1
```

But better is assign scalar if need same all values as pointed [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762302/changing-vocabularies-to-value-1-in-pandas-data-frame/44762350#comment76505564_44762302):

```
df1['ADR'] = 1
print (df1)
   Index  ADR
0      1    1
1      2    1
2      3    1
3      4    1
4      5    1
```

Comment: Glad can help! I add another solution also.